# TypeError: 'Node' Object is not iterable

Tags: python

So I created this node class which has an array of children nodes. Now I want to iterate through the children to find the least cost/value total of all the possible paths. I'm applying the depth first search strategy. But after one of my children has undergone an interation, I get a TypeError saying that "NodeType cannot be iterated"

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cost):
        self.cost= cost
        self.children = None

    def get(self):
        return self.cost

    def findMinPath(self):
        min_val = 10000
        if self.children is None:
            return self.cost
        for child in self.children:
            temp = child.findMinPath()
            if temp<min_val:
                min_val=temp
        return min_val+self.cost

if __name__ =='__main__':
    newnode = Node(0)
    nodeleft= Node(5)
    nodecenter=Node(3)
    noderight=Node(6)
    newnode.children={nodeleft,nodecenter,noderight}
    nodeleft.children=(Node(4))
    Nodecenterleft =Node(2)
    Nodecenterright = Node(0)
    nodecenter.children={Nodecenterleft,Nodecenterright}
    Nodecenterleftleft=Node(1)
    Nodecenterleft.children ={Nodecenterleftleft}
    Nodecenterleftleftright= Node(1)
    Nodecenterleftleft.children={Nodecenterleftleftright}
    Nodecenterrightleft = Node(10)
    Nodecenterright.children={Nodecenterrightleft}
    Noderightleft=Node(1)
    Noderightright=Node(5)
    noderight.children ={Noderightleft,Noderightright}
    print (newnode.findMinPath())
```

The stack trace is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 45, in 
>    print (newnode.findMinPath())
>   File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 17, in findMinPath
>    temp = child.findMinPath()
>   File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 16, in findMinPath
>    for child in self.children:
>   TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
>   [Finished in 0.094s]

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace, and since your code doesn't have line numbers, tell us on what line the error is occurring?

Comment: Any reason for tagging this question with Java?

Comment: Yeah I'm new here @Karthik

Comment: @Steve Yeah    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 45, in <module>
    print (newnode.findMinPath())
  File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 17, in findMinPath
    temp = child.findMinPath()
  File "/Users/yashshah/Desktop/Initializer/tree.py", line 16, in findMinPath
    for child in self.children:
TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
[Finished in 0.094s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
nodeleft.children = (Node(4))
```

it needs to be:

```
nodeleft.children = {Node(4)}
```

Since you can put parens around any expression, Python can't be sure you mean to create a tuple with your version.  So your line is the same as:

```
nodeleft.children = Node(4)
```

And as I expect you already see, your code then ends up thinking it's iterating over a collection of Node objects, but it's really trying to iterate over a single Node object, which isn't kosher.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The mistake is that I should've done nodeleft.children={Node(4)}

Comment: btw, I think you could be using tuples instead of sets, because you are not ever testing for membership.  If you don't need to do that, you could use tuples, which would be faster to iterate over.  But maybe you want to do lookups on these nodes later on, and it probably doesn't make any difference anyway for what you're doing.

Comment: I used tuples and it took 0.156s whereas with set it took 0.142s

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  Well, you're right on then.  I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: Thanks anyway! Was banging my head for almost 20 mins for nothing